# How to manage the code Dynamic Feature Module on app update with feature code?

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module

I am working on dynamic feature module in android. But I couldn't find anything when I update the codebase or change the codebase in Feature Module.

How to handle the codebase, as when checking the getInstalledModules() method returns that it is installed and doesn't install. Is there a way to check if there is any update in the feature code? If no, then how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at this 
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery#manage_app_updates

I think this should be of any help to you.

Also, it is mentioned that

Note: It's okay to request a dynamic feature module that’s already installed on the device. The API instantly considers the request as completed if it detects the module is already installed. Additionally, after a module is installed, Google Play keeps it updated automatically. That is, when you upload a new version of your app bundle, the platform updates all installed APKs that belong to your app. For more information, read Manage app updates.